# jquery.base64.js is not working in jquery1.8.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to generate the Base64 encoded token using jquery plugins.

```
function make_base_auth(username, password) {
    console.log("Generating Base64 token");
    var token = username + ':' + password;  
    var hash = $.base64.encode(token);  
    base_auth = "Basic " + hash;
    return base_auth;
}
```

I have downloaded the plugin from below url. but its not working.

https://github.com/yatt/jquery.base64

I got the below error

```
TypeError: $.base64 is undefined
```

I am using jquery1.8.2, Jquery-mobile-1.1.1

Please help me out on this .

Comment: From the error, you simply not load the plugin right.

Comment: Are you sure that the `jquery.base64.js` is imported to your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure to include the script after including the jQuery script?

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<!-- include extension -->
<script src='jquery.base64.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```